# Embedding Jupyter in Qt Application

Tags: qt, pyqt, python-embedding, jupyter-console

I have a Qt application with an embedded Jupyter QtConsole. This is the code that I use to create the Jupyter console:

```
from qtconsole.rich_jupyter_widget import RichJupyterWidget
from qtconsole.inprocess import QtInProcessKernelManager

class EmbeddedJupyterConsole(RichJupyterWidget):

def __init__(self, gui):
    super(RichJupyterWidget, self).__init__(gui.ipython_container)
    self.kernel_manager = QtInProcessKernelManager()
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel()
    self.kernel        = self.kernel_manager.kernel
    self.kernel.gui    = 'qt4'
    self.kernel_client = self.kernel_manager.client()
    self.kernel_client.start_channels()
    gui.ipython.kernel_manager = self.kernel_manager
    gui.ipython.kernel_client  = self.kernel_client
    gui.ipython.exit_requested.connect(self.stop)

def executeCmd(self, cmd):
    self.kernel.shell.ev(cmd)

def pushVar(self, **kwarg):
    self.kernel.shell.push(kwarg)

def stop(self):
    self.kernel_client.stop_channels()
    self.kernel_manager.shutdown_kernel()
    self.app.exit()
```

And this is the code that I use to generate the main Qt window:

```
class QtMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,app):
    self.console = EmbeddedJupyterConsole(self)
    # Initialize other widgets within the main window

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtMainWindow(app)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Whenever I run this code, the Jupyter console and QtApplication work correctly. However, I also see the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\console_widget.py", line 464, in sizeHint
    font_metrics = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font)
AttributeError: 'EmbeddedJupyterConsole' object has no attribute 'font'
```

If I add add a "fake" font property to the EmbeddedJupyterConsole, then I loose the nice format of the console and the error still appears. Does anyone know what is the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the same PyQt that Jupyter console is using?

Comment: Not sure actually. If I list my Python packages I see pyqt 4.11.4, qt 4.8.7, qtconsole 4.2.1, ipython 5.0.0, jupyter_client 4.3.0 and jupyter_core 4.1.0.